# Wrap labels inside row chart dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I created a row chart using dc.js. Though the label is too long and it can fit inside the chart..How i can wrap it so that it fits within the chart[image]

Comment: the correct tag for dc.js is [dc.js] - that's why i missed this. [dc] is a desktop calculator for Unix.

Comment: svg generally doesn't have any facility for line wrapping text, believe it or not. so this is actually not simple. you'd have to add an event handler for [pretransition](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#on__anchor) and do the line wrapping yourself - if you [search for d3 line wrap](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=d3+line+wrap&t=ffab&ia=qa) you'll find numerous examples, but it's not easy. :-(